# Predisposed supporter of authority views for the supporter's benefit

Tags: single-word-requests

'A person who has a predisposition to support authority views, because they know they will be reinforced for doing so.'

Words that come to mind are: group think, and authoritarian. But is there something more accurate reflecting how they are predisposed, and do it for their benefit?

I'm looking for non-slang, formal words or phrases.

Comment: I'm confused. Mainly die to your using authoratarian. Are you looking for a term describing someone in-charge who enforces rules? Or someone who follows rules to a fault?

Comment: +1 The suggested terms are not in the same sense as the idea quoted, but the question is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

The hard part is to come up with a word that includes the "self-interested" aspect you are looking for, but for the "predisposition" I'd suggest:

- doctrinaire
- zealot
- dogmatic

So, not a single word, but is a "self-interested zealot" what you are looking for?

Comment: I hadn't known 'doctrinaire' before you said it... interesting word. I'm going to have to think about it all more.

Answer (score 0):

How does [**disciplinarian**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disciplinarian#disciplinarian__3) sound?

> A person who believes in or practises firm discipline:

Comment: Just wait. The OP's idea seems a bit different really.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to think of nice/neutral/formal ways to put it but so far no cigar.

However, I think it the following may be relevant to a certain degree:

- [*Mob/Herd Mentality*](http://gog.is/define+mob+mentality) - Herd mentality, or mob mentality, describes how people are influenced by their peers to adopt certain behaviors, follow trends, and/or purchase items.
- *Sheep* - In the sense that they follow the flock and do as ordered by the shepherd.
- *Puppet* - In the sense that they are controlled by a guiding hand.